# How to access the fields of a jqGrid row?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Suppose I have the following (shortened for simplicity):

```
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({
    ...
    ondblClickRow: function(rowid) {
        // I want to access the fields of the double-clicked row in here
    }
    ...
});
```

Inside the ondblClickRow event, I want to access the fields of the row.

How is this done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call the `getCell` method with the `rowid` parameter and a column index.
See the [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods).

Answer (score 1):

If you call the `getRowData` method with the `rowid` parameter, it will return all the data in all the cells of the row.  It will return the cell contents with the `colModel` name of the cell containing the data in an array made of `name:value` pairs.  I think that's more like what you're asking to see, isn't it?