# jqGrid gives undefined columns upon ondblClickRow

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to get specific columns value on dubble click on row.

I have tried solution from these two post but not success:

1. [jqGrid HOWTO: Get the value of specific cell upon double click on row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382751/jqgrid-howto-get-the-value-of-specific-cell-upon-double-click-on-row)
2. [jqGrid gridComplete:- getRowData - get row cell value from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285282/jqgrid-gridcomplete-getrowdata-get-row-cell-value-from-array)

I have following code:

```
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({
    url:'<%=request.getContextPath()%>/peripherals/list',
    datatype: "json",
    mtype:"POST",
    colNames:['Id', 'Name', 'Gateway', 'Type', 'Status', 'Created On', 'status_id'],
    colModel:[{name:'id',index:'id', align:"right",hidden:true},        
                {name:'Name',index:'Name', align:"left", shrinkToFit: true},
                {name:'BoxName',index:'BoxName', align:"left", shrinkToFit: true},
                {name:'Type',index:'Type', align:"left", shrinkToFit: true},
                {name:'Status',index:'Status', align:"left", shrinkToFit: true},
                {name:'Time_Tag',index:'Time_Tag', align:"left", shrinkToFit: true},
                {name:'status_id',index:'status_id', align:"right",hidden:true}
    ],

    height: 500,
    rowNum:50,
    rowList:[10,20,30,50,75,100,500,1000],
    pager: '#pager2',
    sortname: 'id',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption:"",
    ondblClickRow: function(id) {
        var rowData = jQuery(this).getRowData(id);

        var selRow = jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow');
        var data = jQuery(this).jqGrid('getRowData',selRow);
        alert("Type -> "+data.Type + ", Name -> " + data.name); // gives undefined instead of values

        if(rowData['status_id'] == 7){
            jQuery(".alert").show();
            jQuery(".alert").html("<strong>Warning!</strong> "+rowData['Status']+" for "+rowData['Name']);  
        } else {
            window.location ="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/peripherals/detail/" + id;  
        }
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not full clear what you need to implement, but the code of `ondblClickRow` contains some clear errors.

You use the lines

```
var selRow = jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow');
var data = jQuery(this).jqGrid('getRowData',selRow);
```

which will always assign empty object `{}` to `data` because parameter `selRow` should be the rowid, but you have `selRow` equal to `[]` always because `selarrrow` get the array of rowids of **multiselect** grid. You don't use `multiselect: true` option. Thus `selarrrow` have the value `[]`. If you need to get the rowid of selected row then you should use `selrow` instead of `selarrrow`. On the other side you write the code of `ondblClickRow` callback and so it's better just use `id` parameter of the callback.

The second important error exist because of usage `rowData['Status']` inctead of `rowData['status_id']` (or better `rowData.status_id`).

If I correctly understand what you want to do then you should rewrite the implementation of `ondblClickRow` to the following

```
ondblClickRow: function (rowid) {
    var rowData = jQuery(this).getRowData(rowid);

    if (rowData.status_id === "7") {
        jQuery(".alert")
            .html("<strong>Warning!</strong> " + rowData.status_id +
                  " for " + rowData.Name)
            .show();  
    } else {
        location = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/peripherals/detail/" + rowid;  
    }
}
```